# Load individual page - Permissions in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a site written in django with wagtail as cms similar to web shop. When I go to products you don't have to be logged in to view all products. But when you want to see individual you have to be logged in. I didn't write rest framework part of app.
Now I want to turn that off so everyone can see individual product. I don't know what to change, but I know that is REST framework issue.

In wagtail the page is public.

my settings are:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


and views.py

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [OAuth2Authentication, 
    authentication.SessionAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrTokenHasScope, ]
    required_scopes = ['read', 'write', ]
    queryset = Product.objects.live().all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

I don't know what else is required but help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To allow any **UnAuthenticated user** to view individual products, update:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [OAuth2Authentication, 
    authentication.SessionAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ] #change this
    required_scopes = ['read', 'write', ]
    queryset = Product.objects.live().all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

This doesn't completely help unless you explain some extra context like:

- Is everyone allowed to create a Product?
- Is everyone allowed to delete a product?

Anyway with `permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]` allows everyone to do anything. So be cautious.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay,

Only admin can create and delete products from admin page.
The goal of product page is to see details of product which only logged users could do till now, and now i want to allow everyone too see the page and if they click buy to check if they are logged.
Products are basically links to other shop sites with info from those sites.

If I put this AllowAny what can go wrong if only me can access admin page.

Comment: Did you test? Because with your current code anyone can create and delete a product.

Comment: Anyone who has admin privileges can create and delete products in wagtail admin. If you go to site and register and later login all is good. That person can't go to admin page.